# kivy: launcher not working in android 11?

Tags: android, kivy, launcher

I made a small app in kivy from windows 10 and it runs perfectly but I wanted to launch it in android 11 and it only comes out in kivy launcher "No projects are avalible to launche" I have the main.py and android.txt in the app folder inside sdard/kivy/ but it still doesn't appear to launch the app

Comment: can you provide us some logs?